# Scrapy: ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using scrapy to axtract some data, last time I had a problem in the ligne of regx. the error message is like this one :

**File "ProjetVinNicolas3\spiders\nicolas_spider3.py", line 70, in parse_wine_page

```
classement, appelation, couleur = res.select('.//div[@class="pro_col_right"]/div[@class="pro_blk_trans"] div[@class="pro_blk_trans_titre"]/text()').re(r'^(\d\w+\s*Vin)\S\s+(\w+-\w+|\w+)\S\s+(\w+)\s*$')
exceptions.ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack**
```

[link program](https://gist.github.com/XeroxGH/295c723c565d889fb2dc)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `.re` is returning a zero-length tuple. You cannot perform a sequence assignment to n variables using a sequence which is not of exactly length n.

Comment: when i try this line (n° 70) on scrapy shell, it works and it gives correct results !!!

Comment: @xeroxSO In that case, you're using different input data, such that you get 3-tuple.

Comment: thank you for advice, i tryed to put each var in a line:
https://gist.github.com/XeroxGH/6c40ef4fe332c55b636a

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
classement, appelation, couleur  = res.select('.//div[@class="pro_col_right"]/div[@class="pro_blk_trans"]/div[@class="pro_blk_trans_titre"]/text()').re(r'^(\d\w+\s*Vin)\S\s+(\w+\-\w+|\w+)\S\s+(\w+)\s*$')
```

For example, select returns `[u'Lussac-Saint-Emilion, Rouge']` and it doesn't match your regular expression. See this page http://www.nicolas.com/fr/18_409_9394_chateaubelairmagnum.htm - the content of `pro_blk_trans_titre` div doesn't fit into the format you are asking for.

Rethink your regular expression.